# How to Export just a Function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to export only one function, except other functions and import it in other file.

```
function messsageReceived(message) {

      //print message

  }
function readData(){ 

    // reads data.

  }
module.exports = mqtt_messsageReceived();
```

I want to use **mqtt_messsageReceived** in other file.

Comment: Remove the `()`. You don[t want to invoke it, you just want to reference it. Also, you haven't defined `mqtt_messsageReceived` anywhere in the code above...

Comment: yes, it is actually messageReceived. Editing Typo.

Comment: `module.exports = messageReceived;` would be good

Comment: after that, you can `var mqtt_messageReceived = require('./somefile');` and call `mqtt_messageReceived`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To export just a single function from a module:

Module file:

```
//function definition
function function_name(){...}

//Export
module.exports = function_name;
```

Import:

```
const function_name = require('<relative path>/module_name');

//call imported function 

function_name();
```

---

To export multiple functions:

Module file:

```
//function definitions
function function_name1(){...}
function function_name2(){...}

//Exports
module.exports.function_name1= function_name1;
module.exports.function_name2= function_name2;
```

Import:

```
const module_name = require('<relative path>/module_name');// This returns module object with the functions from module's file.

//call imported function 
module_name.function_name1();
module_name.function_name2();
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was declare a variable and store the functions there.

```
var messages = {

  getMessage : function(){

  },
  readData : function(){

  }
}
module.exports = messages;
```

Then I called both functions from another file and both are working.

```
var message = require('./message');
message.getMessage();
message.readData();
```

I was getting confused because now the file where the functions are won't work if I directly do `node message.js`. I have to call them from another file from where I am importing them.

Comment: In question, you had mentioned that you want only one function to be exported and here you are exporting all the function in `messages` object.

Comment: If you are calling the functions in module js itself, you shouldn't be wrapping them into object. Please check my answer.

Comment: @KetanYekale yes thank you. but I will be adding more functions later on too. and i want to call them in other places too. then I will need the help of a property. cause the code will get manageable more.

Answer (score 0):

You can export only 1 function using the following ways
1.

```
module.exports = function messsageReceived(message) {

    //print message

}

function readData() {

    // reads data.
}
```

2.

```
function messsageReceived(message) {

    //print message

}

function readData() {

    // reads data.
}

module.exports = messsageReceived;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two way :

```
module.exports = {
    MyFunction(parameter){
       console.log('export function');
    }
};
```

**Another one is :**

```
fuction MyFunction(){
   console.log('export function');
}
module.exports.MyFuntion= Myfuction;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export function by Using Following Code :

```
var messsageReceived=function(message){
// your code here
}
module.exports = {
    messsageReceived: messsageReceived
}
```